# Micropost Delete Method won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can't seem to get my delete method to work on a micropost, heres the code:

Code for delete link:

```
<%= link_to "delete", micropost, :class => "delete_link",
                                 :method => :delete,
                                 :confirm => "You sure?",
                                 :title => micropost.content %>
```

The micropost controller:

```
  def destroy
     @micropost.destroy
     redirect_back_or root_path
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.1 uses unobtrusive javascript now. Now the javascript has been moved out of the link, and into external js files. Make sure you have this in your layout:
  layout/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

or

If you use ':defaults' like following, in layout/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Then you should specify following in application.rb

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery.min jquery_ujs)
```

Comment: I have the include_tag :defaults line, how do I use the config.action_view with my setup?

Comment: In view/layout/application.html.erb  use  `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`